# Pylint: disable warning for subclass

Tags: python, pylint

I'm using pylint in a project and something bother me.

For example, I create a unit test (subclass of unittest.TestCase). This parent class has a lot of method, so pylint say "R0904: Too many public methods".
To "solve" this warning, I disable localy this check.

But I need to write a lot of unit test and it bothers me to disable localy this check each time.

So I'm looking for a way to disable this check for all subclass of unittest.TestCase. 
In a pylint config file may be, but I didn't found anything.

Have you got any idea to do that ?

Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: Hopefully there's a simpler option, but if not… you can always write a plugin that subclasses (or monkeypatches, but subclassing seems cleaner here) the design checker. I'd do it by adding a new option `ignore-test-classes` and use that to skip the `max-public-methods` check for any class that inherits from any of the ignored classes. (The code that handles the class checker's `ignore-iface-methods` should be a good model.) In fact, this seems like it may be of sufficiently general use that you could likely submit it upstream if you do it.

Comment: Doesn't quite get you there, but you can always drop a `pylintrc` into a package (i.e. any directory with an `__init__.py` in it), so if you have all your tests in one `tests` directory, for instance, you can at least disable it on a project basis, even if not globally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Abarnert, I will check how to create a plugin for that. My issue is not only for unittest class. For example, I use sqlalchemy and for subclass of sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator.
I'll try to write a generic plugin to add a option like disable-XXXX=unittest.TestCase,...,...

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `pylintrc` file and run pylint using that. You can do that as follows:

```
$ pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc
```

This generates the default pylintrc file. This should have a paragraph that looks like:

```
# Disable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You
# can either give multiple identifier separated by comma (,) or put this option
# multiple time (only on the command line, not in the configuration file where
# it should appear only once).
#disable=
```

You want to add the following line after that paragraph (but within the *MESSAGES CONTROL* section):

```
disable=R0904
```

or:

```
disable=too-many-public-methods
```

You then need to run pylint with that rcfile. This can be done using the `--rcfile=<file>` argument.